# difference between pop3 and imap

Tags: coldfusion

I am new to cold fusion. I have read some of the articles regarding imap and pop. I am little confused ,can any one help me out what is difference between pop and imap precisely .If possible , a good working code would be appreciated. Thank-you.

Comment: http://www.pop2imap.com/

Comment: What have you tried? Provide some code and let us know what is different between what is expected and what actually happens. No one will just give you the code. You need to show you did a little work yourself.

Comment: (Edit) If you are new to Stack Overflow, please read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, rather than a discussion forum. As written, your question is too broad and is likely to be closed. Questions are typically expected to involve code you have already tried, for example: *"I learning about feature X and would like to do {....}. I have read the documentation and tried code Y, but am getting error Z.".*

Answer (score 4):

POP3 and IMAP are two different protocols (methods) used to access email.

Of the two, IMAP is the better options and the recommended option when you need to check your emails from multiple devices, such as a work laptop, a home computer, or a tablet, smartphone, or other mobile device. Tap into your synced (updated) account from any device with IMAP.

POP3 downloads email from a server to a single computer, then deletes it from the server. Because your messages get downloaded to a single computer or device and then deleted from the server, it can appear that mail is missing or disappearing from your Inbox if you try to check your mail from a different computer.

Comment: thankyou @rohit . Can u provide me a working example?

Comment: Do you mean code or protocol's working?

Comment: codes.Basically i want to know how to run it. how would i tell the code who's mails should be downloaded/filtered?

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentations for [cfpop](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f96.html) and [cfimap](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WS371453EC-36D5-44ce-BF1E-750E3016BBD6.html) tags, I think you will understand.

**Answer for a comment**

The main thing you need to understand is that you wont be able to make a search request to server and get only the emails with search string.

```
<cfimap action="open" connection="Conn" server="imap.gmail.com" username="xxxxxxx@foo.bar" password="password" secure="yes" port="993" >
<cfimap action="getAll" connection="Conn" name="EmailQueryName" folder="Inbox" maxrows="1">
```

The above opens a connection and reads emails. `maxrows="1"` denotes that we are only fetching one row now. This is added for the testing purpose only. The `action="getAll"` or `action="GETHEADERONLY"` creates a query with variable name `name="EmailQueryName"`. You can also provide a `attachmentpath` attribute which is used for saving the attachments. The query which is returned will have the columns like,  `ANSWERED, ATTACHMENTFILES, ATTACHMENTS, BODY, CC, CIDS, DELETED, DRAFT, FLAGGED, FROM, HEADER, HTMLBODY, LINES, MESSAGEID, MESSAGENUMBER, RECENT, REPLYTO, RXDDATE, SEEN, SENTDATE, SIZE, SUBJECT, TEXTBODY, TO, UID`. Using this you can use [Query of Query](http://www.quackit.com/coldfusion/tutorial/coldfusion_query_of_queries.cfm), to filter data, or you can even save details to database before doing that.

If you are going to get all your emails, then it is going to take a lot of time and make sure the value for request timeout is a big value.

Comment: <cfimap 
<!--code here-->
  uid = "integer or comma-delimited list of integers" 
  username = "SMTP user ID"> 
what is uid and username? how would i tell the code who's mails should be downloaded?

Comment: @MiliBiswas I made changes on the answer.

Comment: thankyou.. your answer clread all my doubts